# Angular Form Builder Optional Required field

Tags: angular2-forms, angular2-formbuilder

I want to set a field of a formbuilder become required or un-required based on the option of another field.

For example, If I have 2 options "over 18" or "under 18" and one filed "age".
If I select option "over 18". I have to make the "age" field become required (mandatory). 
If I select option "under 18". The "age" field become non-required.

How can I build up that requirement with form-builder? I tried a lot, but nothing works.

Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if there is a way to do this directly with FormBuilder, but you should be able to accomplish this by binding to `[required]` in your template input.

`<input type='text' formControlName='age' [required]="form.get('over18').value === 'true'">`

`form` being the name of your `FormGroup` and `true` being the value of your checkbox/radio input.

Doing this will invalidate your form if `over18` field is `true` and nothing is entered into the `age` field.

Comment: This is a great answer.